# "'str' object is not callable" in urls.py in Django Project

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm getting the TypeError *'str' object is not callable* in my Django Project when i access the url "localhost:8000/adminPonto" of the project (i'm brazillian). It follows below the codes of *urls.py* (within the error lies) and *adminApp.views* (code related to urls.py and, consequently, to the error):

urls.py

`# -- coding:iso-8859-1 --`

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import baterPonto.views
import adminApp.views
import PontoCOSGEM.views

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Sistema de Ponto
(r'^ponto/$',baterPonto.views.index), # Pagina inicial da administracao do registro de ponto
(r'^ponto/registrar/$',baterPonto.views.registrar_ponto),

# Administracao do Ponto
(r'^adminPonto/$',adminApp.views.loginIndex), # Formulario de login da admin. de ponto
(r'^adminPonto/login/$',adminApp.views.entrar), # Pagina de login da admin. de ponto
(r'^adminPonto/logout/$',adminApp.views.sair), # Pagina de logout da admin. de ponto
(r'^adminPonto/index/$',adminApp.views.index), # Pagina inicial do sistema de adm.

# Gerencia de Funcionarios
(r'^adminPonto/funcionarios/$',adminApp.views.funcionariosIndex), # Menu de gerência dos funcionarios
'''(r'^adminPonto/funcionarios/search/$',adminApp.views.funcionariosSearch), # Procura por funcionario
(r'^adminPonto/funcionarios/add/$',adminApp.views.funcionariosAdd), # Adiciona funcionarios
(r'^adminPonto/funcionarios/edit/$',adminApp.views.funcionariosEdit), # Edita funcionarios
(r'^adminPonto/funcionarios/delete/$',adminApp.views.funcionariosDelete), # Apaga funcionarios
(r'^adminPonto/funcionarios/list/$',adminApp.views.funcionariosList), # Lista todos os funcionarios'''

# Relatorio de Ponto
(r'^adminPonto/relatorios/$',adminApp.views.relatorioIndex), # Menu de relatorio de ponto (por funcionario ou de todos) 


# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'PontoCOSGEM.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^PontoCOSGEM/', include('PontoCOSGEM.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

views.py

`# -- coding: iso-8859-1 --`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def userLoged(request,url):
insertMessage = False
testUser = ""

try:
    testUser = request.session['user']

except KeyError:
    insertMessage = True
    message = "É preciso estar logado para acessar esta página."
    return render_to_response('loginAdmin.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request));

if testUser is not None:
    return render_to_response(url,locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request));
else:
    insertMessage = True
    message = "É preciso estar logado para acessar esta página."
    return render_to_response('loginAdmin.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request));

def loginIndex(request):
return render_to_response('loginAdmin.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def entrar(request):
insertMessage = False
message = "Erro. Usuário ou Senha incorretos."
lg = "Usuario"
passwd = "Senha"

username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

if user is not None:
    request.session['user'] = user
    return     render_to_response('indexAdmin.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request));
else:
    insertMessage = True
    return render_to_response('loginAdmin.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request));

def sair(request):
insertMessage = True
message = "Saída realizada com sucesso."
logout(request)
return render_to_response('loginAdmin.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request));

def index(request):
userLoged(request,'indexAdmin.html')

# Gerência de funcionarios
def funcionariosIndex(request):
userLoged(request,'funcionarioIndex.html')

'''def funcionariosSearch(request):


def funcionariosAdd(request):


def funcionariosEdit(request):


def funcionariosDelete(request):


def funcionariosList(request):'''


# Gerência de relatórios
def relatorioIndex(request):
return HttpResponse("Menu de escolha de relatorios")

# Create your views here.
```

Honestly, I can't get see errors in code above, and i don't know why this error is occurring.

Does anyone, so, knows why the *'str' object is not callable* is appearing?

Comment: Usually it's a forgotten comma. Can you show the traceback so we know what line it appears on?

Comment: can you show the stacktrace ?

Comment: Just an observation: codes above are not idented for purpose of pasting in this question. Other local in which codes above are available: http://pastebin.com/vPgAATFm

Comment: here it is: http://dpaste.com/1409769/

Comment: Updated: http://dpaste.com/1409771/

Answer (score 0):

Multiline comments like '''comment text''' can cause troubles.

Try commenting five lines from

```
'''(r'^adminPonto/funcionarios/search/$',adminApp.views.funcionariosSearch), # Procura por funcionario
```

with '#' and tell if it helps.

Comment: That's not a comment. It's a string.